# Can't Discover host's on network but myself

Tags: wifi

I'm connected to my network using a wifi usb adapter but when ever i do a scan using nmap or ettercap i can't discover any other host's but my self? What is going on. I added images of what shows up when i run ifconfig and iwconfig i also added my settings for the vmware

[image]
[image]

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/1fR1k

Comment: How are you scanning?  Also, do not post images of text.  Images of text make things harder to compare against.

Comment: nmap -sP 192.168.1.1/24   it returns with one host found which is my system

Comment: @Bernal make sure your network is setup to bridge otherwise VMs put you on a private network. That happened to me when I first started setting up vulnerable VMs on my network. It's like the least documented thing ever.

Comment: It is on bridged, i just did a scan and it worked but when i retried it , it said 0 hosts up

Comment: @Bernal can you ping your kali box from a separate machine?

Comment: yes it shows up on the network as being there

Comment: @Bernal What happens when you ping google.com and when you ping another machine on your network?

Comment: i get replies from both

Comment: @Bernal so if you can ping the machines your VM can see them. What happens when you run 'nmap <one of your target ip's> '

Comment: it discovers hosts sometimes but when i retry i wont work, i have to restart the vmware for it to work again... i don't know what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the only host you see is yourself, it's very likely that your wireless network has [client isolation](http://www.howtogeek.com/179089/lock-down-your-wi-fi-network-with-your-routers-wireless-isolation-option/) enabled -- this prevents clients from being able to directly talk to each other, which is exactly the behavior you have described.

Comment: can this be disabled?

Answer (score -2):

It is set on bridged, I just tried doing a scan and it shows all the hosts but when I retried it on ettercap the issue came back

Comment: This is better as a comment or update your question with this information.